# How to to get part of the string

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following function can return 9 digits from the string.

my question is if I pass abc="123456" which means its low than 9 digits.It shows error.I need maximum 9 digits from the given strings.if I pass six digit ,I need the six digit string instead of the Error.

```
public string test()
{
  string abc="asdhfjsdfkjhfiovjalksdhafbvklxkjszjhd";
  return abc.Substring(0, 9);
}
```

Comment: return abc.Length < 9 ? abc : abc.Substring(0, 9);

Comment: Although peoples dislike for the ternary operator might prevent that from being a top rated answer

Comment: @AdamKewley People dislike it? I use it all the time.

Comment: Based on anecdotal evidence gathered from SO lurking, it is generally disliked; usually, because it is overused. The most cited reason being it's relative inability to extend or be commented. EDIT: before people jump on that, I'm aware you *can* comment inside them, just that it generally isn't stylistically nice.

Comment: @AdamKewley I think problems arise when you try to put too much logic in the statement or try to chain them together like i've seen e.g. `foo = foo.Length < 9 ? "bar" : foo.Length >= 9 ? "foobar" : etc...`. Otherwise they're fine IMO.

Comment: @DGibbs Yeah. I actually would prefer if the syntax was a little nicer for them once they go multiline. Coming from F# it is a little annoying having to use `if...else` expressions. But, again, that is a personal bias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (abc.Length < 9)
    return abc;
else
    return abc.Substring(0, 9);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
abc.Substring(0, Math.Min(9, abc.Length));
```

When your string will be shorter than 9 it will return full string

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
string newStr = new string(abc.Take(9).ToArray());
```

But using `Substring` is better.